# Get the value of input text element after pressing submit button in django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm a newbie to Django and started learning it last week. My question is I have a web page which has an input text box and a submit button. **I want to capture the input string** entered in the next web page (redirecting page) which has been entered in the text box after pressing the submit button in Django.

[image: This is how the initial web page looks like]

I have tried the following:

> views.py

```
#View for the initial page
def index(request):
    return render( request, 'index.html')

#View for the Redirecting page -- This is where I want to catch the text box input
def results(request):
    inp_value = request.GET.get('text_search', 'This is a default value')
    context = {'inp_value': inp_value}
    return render( request, 'results.html', context)
```

> forms.py

```
from django import forms

class TextForm(forms.Form):
    text_search = forms.CharField(label='Text Search', max_length=100)
```

> index.html

```
<form action="/searcher/results/" method="get">
        <label for="results">Enter a string: </label>
        <input id="results" type="text" name="results" value="{{ search_results }}">
        <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>
```

Can anyone point out why I'm not able to get the value of the textbox?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.GET` key is the name of the input. So, in your case, since you want the value of `<input type="text" name="results">` you should get that value from `request.GET.get('results')`.

However, there is also a `{{ search_results }}` value that it's not get rendered from your `index` view. Thus, it will always be null.

```
def results(request):
    inp_value = request.GET.get('results', 'This is a default value')
    context = {'inp_value': inp_value}
    return render( request, 'results.html', context)
```